# When using Collections.sort - no instance of Variable T exist so that Collection conforms etc

Tags: java, sorting, generics, collections

so I've build these two classes:
 1. Genre which implements Comparable 
 2. GenreManager which takes a Collection of genres and creates an internal copy of it. Later in GenreManager, I will need to add new Genres by getting a name as an input, and I need to assign this Genre the next free id number, which is basically the next smallest positive number after the smallest used id.

I am trying to use Collections.sort() to sort my list but I am getting the following error: 
"no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Collection conforms to List." and I am not sure what this is referring to... I've tried ready a bunch of posts about this on here but couldn't figure out the solution... Here is part of the code:

```
public class Genre implements Comparable<Genre>{

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Genre(int id, String name){
        this.id = Validate.requireNonNegative(id);
        this.name = Validate.requireNonNullNotEmpty(name);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Genre o) {
        int res = Integer.valueOf(id).compareTo(o.id);
        if (res != 0){
            return res;
        }
        else{
            return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(o.name);
        }
    }
 }
```

```
public class GenreManager{

    private Collection<Genre> genres;
    private Collection<Genre> sortedTree;

    public GenreManager(){
        this.genres = new ArrayList<Genre>();
    }

    public GenreManager(Collection<Genre> genres){
        // check for duplicates
        for (Genre x : genres){
            for (Genre y : genres){
                if (x.equals(y) || x.getName().equals(y.getName()))
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("List contains duplicates");
            }
        }

        this.genres = new ArrayList<Genre>(Collections.sort(genres));    
    }
}
```

I am trying to do the sorting in the constructor above. Can someone tell me how to go around this?

I tried playing around a little bit, trying to change the private variable from `Collection<Genre>` to `List<Genre>` for example and similar things but nothing worked... I also tried casting the input of the .sort method to (`List<Genre>`) but it didn't work either.

PS: I can't change any of the method header or class headers.

Thanks!

Comment: You know that your `GenreManager` will throw that `IllegalArgumentException` whenever the list of genres is not empty? That's because you compare every element with every element, i.e. even elements with themselves. Besides that, that's not very efficient - using a set, e.g. a `LinkedHashSet`, might be better.

Comment: `Collections.sort` returns `void`.

Comment: After you've fixed the checks (and btw, you could use a `TreeSet` and get duplicate checks and sorting in one go) try `this.genres = new ...; Collections.sort(this.genres);`.

Comment: @Thomas Hey Thomas, you are right. I added another if statement in the second loop which checks if (x == y) and in that case continues to the next iteration.... That should solve that problem right? I am still getting the same error regarding the collections.sort()


And you are right, but I just tried this.genres = new ArrayList<Genre>(genres) and then Collections.sort(this.genres) but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: The other problem is `private Collection<Genre> genres;` - a collection isn't sortable by default and if you look at `Collections.sort(List<T>)` you see that you need to provide a list (which is a _sorted_ collection). Thus change the definition of the `genres` field to `List<Genre>` and it should work (or at least compile).

Comment: @Thomas, would you please explain how it would be different to check for duplicates by using a Treeset? Wouldn't I still have to compare all elements with each other, or is there a built in function to do that? 

The problem is, is that my equals method of Genre returns true only by checking the ID, but in the other class, I also need to check the Name of the Genre, which the equals method doesn't do.

Comment: `TreeSet`  doesn't use `equals()` but either the `compareTo()` method of the elements if they implement `Comparable` or the provided `Comparator`. It automatically sorts the elements based on the compare result and whenever you get a result of 0 it will assume the elements are equal and reject the alledged duplicate. Using `TreeSet` your constructor's time complexity would go from O(n*n) down to O(n*log(n)).

Comment: @Thomas Hey thanks for the answer again. I did what you said with changing the private Variable to List<Genre> and it magically worked now, although I could almost swear that I did that before I posted this but I must have still missed something. It seems to be working now! I'll try to use a TreeSet rather than my method as that does seem to make more sense. I was actually planning to do that, as you can see in my private Variables, I did have a variable named sortedTree. 

If you'd post your answer again as an answer, I could mark it as a solution then. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per request, here's a compilation of my comments to answer the question:

The immediate problem is that `Collections.sort(List<T>)` takes a `List` parameter and not just a `Collection` because collections in general don't have to be sortable (e.g. hash sets aren't). Additionally the method returns `void` and sorts the passed list in place, i.e. the way you call it won't compile.

Taking all this into consideration your code might be changed to something like this:

```
public class GenreManager{
   private List<Genre> genres;
   ...

   public GenreManager(Collection<Genre> genres){
     ... 

     //create a list out of the passed collection
     this.genres = new ArrayList<Genre>( genres );

     //sort the list    
     Collections.sort(this.genres);
   }
}
```

The other problem with the code you posted is that for any non-empty collection it will throw the `IllegalArgumentException` because elements are compared to themselves. Adding a check for `x != y` to the condition would solve that but the code is still somewhat slow because it has a time complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>).

This can be solved to use a set instead of a list. However, a `HashSet` would depend on how `equals()` and `hashCode()` define equality, which doesn't seem to match your requirements. That could be solved by using a wrapper object that implements both methods as needed.

A better approach might be to use a `TreeSet` though. `TreeSet` uses comparisons to determine order and equality (if the compare result is 0) and thus would allow you to either let your `Genre` class implement `Comparable` as you did or provide a separate `Comparator` (e.g. if you need multiple different definitions of equality).

If you just want to eliminate duplicates, your code could then look like this:

```
public class GenreManager{
   private SortedSet<Genre> genres;
   ...

   public GenreManager(Collection<Genre> genres){
     this.genres = new TreeSet<>( genres );
   }
}
```

If you want to know what duplicates are in the collection you could do it like this:

```
public GenreManager(Collection<Genre> genres){
  this.genres = new TreeSet<>(); //the generic type is inferred from this.genres

  for( Genre element : genres ) {
    //If the element didn't exist in the set add() will return true, false if it existed  
    boolean nonDuplicate = this.genres.add( element );

    //handle the duplicate element here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned before, your code has several errors which makes it unusable:

1. Checking equality of elements with themselves.
2. Collections.sort method takes a List of Comparable as an argument, when Collection is a little higher in a hierarchy, which means you can't use it as a parameter. To resolve it change declaration of variable genres to List.
3. method Collections.sort returns void, so you can't pass its return value as an argument to ArrayList constructor. Instead, try assigning genres variable first and then sorting it via Collections.sort as

`this.genres = new ArrayList/LinkedList(genres) 
 Collections.sort(this.genres)`

Again, you may consider using TreeSet as it holds all elements sorted and without duplicates, so your constructor will just look like

`this.genres = new TreeSet(genres)`

In addition, it prevents duplicates even during adding, so if you have 10 elements, adding already existing one won't make any changes to your set. But using this data structure you should check variable for null before adding, as it will produce `NullPointerException`