# Java wont sort arraylist of abstract classes

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object

I have a problem.I write simple abstract class and i try to sort array list of that class and i implemented Comparator interface for compareTo function but List.sort gives an error.Please help.Here is a code:

```
public abstract class Antena implements Comparator<Antena>{
    private double x, y;

    public Antena(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Antena o1, Antena o2) {
        return (int)(o1.getX()-o2.getX());
    }
}
```

In main class i have:

```
List<Antena> anteneObj=new ArrayList<>();
anteneObj.add(.....);
....
....
Collections.sort(anteneObj);
```

This gives me an error and wont sort list.What is a problem?Am i supposed to extends or implement something in extended classes. Of course i have 2 classes that extends abstract Antena class.

Comment: *This gives me an error* Which error?

Comment: `double` has a **much** larger range than `int` - using `a - b` and casting to an `int` is a really rather bad idea...

Comment: You are sorting instances of `Antena`, so it needs to implement [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), not `Comparator<T>`.

Comment: No instance of type variable T exists so that Antena conforms to Comparable<? super T>

Comment: I also tried with comparable but wont work.

Comment: What do you mean by "wont work", when implementing `Comparable`?

Comment: This gives me the same error

Comment: At which line do you get that error?

Comment: At Collection.sort(anteneObj);

Comment: Did you have `Collection<Antena> anteneObj` in place of `List<Antena> anteneObj` earlier? Found [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48888636/when-using-collections-sort-no-instance-of-variable-t-exist-so-that-collection?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), which suggests that may have been the case. If yes, try clean building.

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from [`Collections.sort(List<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-):

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the
>    `Comparable` natural ordering of its elements.
>    All elements in the list must implement the `Comparable` interface.

Therefore, in order to be sortable by `Collections.sort(List<T>)`
your class `Antena` should implement interface `Comparable<Antena>`
instead of `Comparator<Antena>`:

```
public abstract class Antena implements Comparable<Antena> {

    ....

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Antena o) {
        return Double.compare(this.getX(), o.getX());
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried exactly like this but i have the same error.

Comment: No instance of type variable T exists so that Antena conforms to Comparable<? super T>

Answer (score -1):

`compare` method shall return -1 or 0 or 1. Your implementation may return wrong values. Implement Comparable and return `Double.compare(double,  double)`.

Comment: No function return SOMETHING greater lower or exactly 0.Problem is not there

Comment: While the comment (and it is a comment, not an answer) comes to the right conclusion, the assertion that "_`compare` method shall return -1 or 0 or 1_" is false. If you were to read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) - "_Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object._".